# How to symbolize islands differently from larger countries in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I'm trying to recreate this figure (https://figshare.com/articles/journal_contribution/Topographic_and_thematic_in_visibility_of_Small_Island_Developing_States_in_a_world_map/12038586) using my own data in ArcGIS Pro.

I'm especially interested in the leader lines and circles/squares used for island nations. The only way I can think to come up with this is to make the island nations their own point layer and make the symbology for that layer different than the symbology for the layer with all of the other countries. However, I'm using a graduated scale for fill, and I haven't been able to make the fill colors for both layers the same since the main country layer is polygons and the islands layer is points.

Comment: Have you looked at key numbering/labels?  See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/text/key-numbering.htm.  In terms of your point and polygon approach, you could add your layer twice, and use definition queries to put the larger countries in one and islands in the other, and then symbolize/label each as you wish.

Comment: You seem to be trying to find an answer for your original unanswered question. To do that I think you should heavily revise it using additional information from this one and at least one picture.